# SSIS c# script component (not task!) combining / extending recordset variables

Tags: c#, loops, ssis, recordset

I am facing a problem, which - in my opinion - shouldn't be as difficult as it seems to me right now... but somehow I am stuck:

In my ControlFlow in SSIS I have a "For Each" Loop, which contains a DataFlow. This DataFlow executes numerous queries (which have a identical result structure) and writes them to a recordset variable. So far so good - if not evry iteration in the loop would overwrite the existing content in the record set variable.

The idea is to have ALL results of ALL iterations stored in the record set variable.

if I try the following

`OleDbDataAdapter olead = new OleDbDataAdapter();
 olead.Fill(tbltmp, Variables.Ziel);`

I receive an error "Object is not an ADODB.RecordSet or an ADODB.Record"

If I try the following

```
ADODB.RecordSet rs = Variables.Ziel as ADODB.RecordSet;
```

simply nothing seems to happen...

How can I make my Component to extend the recordset variable instead of overwriting its content???

Comment: You are calling the  OleDbDataAdapter constructor with no parameters.  You  need a connection and a command with a query like  : new OleDbDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection);  See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, that wasn't the problem... after all I found a solution: seemingly a data table populated by the component is automatically treated as ADODB recordset whereas a datatable populated from a recordset variable is not. So the solutionw as to manually build a ADODB recordset and then assign this again to a recordset variable. I found the relevant hin here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10503/Simplest-code-to-convert-an-ADO-NET-DataTable-to-a

Comment: I guess there are two solutions.  One using ADODB and one using OleDbDataAdapter.  You used the first solution and I proposed the second solution.

Comment: I use the OleDbDataAdapter (as described in my original post) nevertheless - in order to populate the DataTable with the current recordset variable content. Anyways, considering it would work with the constructor as you propose: in which way would the Select statement have to be designed, considering that I need to query the content of the RecordSet Variable?

Comment: There is no difference between the results of ADODB and Oledb.  They are just different interfaces to the same database.  So the select could be "Select * from table1" which will get all the columns.  Instead of the asterisks you can specify which columns you want in any order.

Comment: Hm... OK, but the query is performed earlier (data flow) - the OleDbAdapter is performing some kind of "dummy query" against the Recordset, not against a DB / Table / whatever... so "olead.Fill(tbltmp, Variables.Ziel);" populates the datatable tbltmp with the recordset content of Varialbles.Ziel. Would it be possible to perform something like "SELECT * FROM Variables.Ziel"? Never encountered this approach before.

Comment: The MSJET which is being used as the driver has two modes : Table and Text.  The error is occuring because the wrong one is being used.            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.TableDirect;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: Ah, OK - didn't know this. I will give it a try. Thanks for clarification!